# How do I select the min opendate from a list of duplicates?

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 columns. SSN|AccountNumber|OpenDate
1 SSN may have multiple AccountNumbers
Each AccountNumber has a corresponding OpenDate

In my list I have many SSN's, each containing several account numbers which may have been opened on different days.

I want the results of my query to be SSN|earlest OpenDate|AccountNumber that corresponds with the earliest opendate.

I'm dealing with about 200,000 records.

EDIT: First I did
    select SSN, min(OpenDate), AcctNumber from Table Group By SSN, AccountNumber
but that didn't quite give me the correct data.

```
    The raw data gives me something like this:
    SSN | AcctNumber | OpenDate
    ---------------------------
    10   101          Jan
    10   102          Feb
    10   103          Mar
```

Where I got 10, Jan, and AccNumber 102 which is not the account number that is associated with Jan OpenDate After looking at others, I found that the account number I got was just one of the account numbers associated with that SSN rather than the one that corresponds with the min(OpenDate)

Comment: Have you tried `select ssn, min(OpenDate), acctNumber from tbl group by ssn, acctNumber`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But there is nothing in that statement that specifies which account number to return.

Comment: However, that statement reliably gives me the earliest available opendate.

Comment: my statement specifies exactly which account number to return.  It returns every row that has a distinct SSN/AcctNumber pair.  For duplicates, it selects the min(OpenDate).

Answer (score 0):

If your table is like this:

```
SSN | AcctNumber | OpenDate
---------------------------
10    101          April
10    101          May
10    102          April
20    201          June
20    201          July
```

Do you want your query to return this?

```
SSN | AcctNumber | OpenDate
---------------------------
10    101          April
10    102          April
20    201          June
```

Then you would use this query:

```
select ssn, min(OpenDate), acctNumber from tbl group by ssn, acctNumber
```

Comment: expected result is: SSN|earlest OpenDate|AccountNumber that corresponds with the earliest opendate.

Comment: @nee21, oops, fixed.  My query was right but me expected results table was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
select SSN , AcctNumber, OpenDate
 from (SELECT SSN , AcctNumber, OpenDate
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SSN, ORDER BY OpenDate ASC ) AS RN
    FROM table) AS temp
WHERE temp.RN= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE AS ( SELECT SSN, AcctNumber, OpenDate, ROW_NUM() OVER (PARTITION BY SSN ORDER BY OpenDate DESC) AS RN ) SELECT SSN, AcctNumber, OpenDate FROM CTE WHERE RN=1;